# In front of people/to people (around people)

Tags: spoken-english

Does "in front of people" sound natural in English?
.

> It is how you present yourself in front of people.
>
> It is how you present yourself to people.

(It is how you present yourself when you are around people)

---

Edited: Is is ----> It is.

Comment: So @JustinStafford, will it sound okay to use "in front of"? "It is how you present yourself in front of people". Does it sound natural and likely to be used by a native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *in front of* is natural. (at least sometimes)

First, using ***to***:

> It is how you present yourself to people.

As an example of usage, this sentence might follow another sentence that tells you what *"It"* isn't; (the ***"it"*** here basically means *'the important thing'*).

You might combine the sentences with a semicolon:

> "It isn't about how nice your clothes are, or how straight your teeth are; it is how you present yourself to people (*that really matters*)".

Now, for your question:

> It is how you present yourself in front of people.

This is fine, and it means the same thing.  It places the focus more squarely on the listener and less on the relationship between the listener and the people with which he interacts.  But this is a subtle distinction.

I should mention that it is a bit redundant, though.  For example *"It is how you present yourself"* would often suffice.

Thus, with *"in front of"* you would more often see things like

> It is how you conduct yourself in front of people.
>
> It is how you behave in front of people.
>
> It is how you handle yourself in front of people.
>
> It is how you act in front of people.
>
> It is how you comport yourself in front of people.
>
> It is your behavior in front of people.
>
> It is your comportment in front of people.

These all mean the same thing, but have slightly different connotations.  For example, *"comportment"* refers to good behavior.

The sentences might be referring to the individuals that the listener interacts with from day to day, or they might refer to a person speaking to a larger audience.

We don't even need these verbs, though, if we don't want them.  In some cases it is enough to say

> It is how you are in front of people.